# Postman: "The input is not a valid base64 encoded string"

Tags: java, jwt, auth0

For a school project I'm trying to use a JWT token as authentication, when the JWT token contains the role "coach", it means that the user is authorized to do something.

I wrote the method that creates a String, and one that should decode it, but when I put the string that I get into Postman, I get a 500 internal server error because according to Postman, it's not a valid base64-encoded string.
In jwt.io, it decodes without any problems...

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("wisebite");

public String login() {
    String jwtToken = JWT.create()
            .withIssuer("wisebite")
            .withSubject("wisebitedetails")
            .withClaim("role", "coach")
            .withIssuedAt(new Date())
            .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000L))
            .withJWTId(UUID.randomUUID()
                    .toString())
            .withNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000L))
            .sign(algorithm);
    return jwtToken;
}

public boolean hasAcces (String jwtToken) {
    JWTVerifier jwtVerifier = JWT.require(algorithm).withIssuer("wisebite").build();
    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = jwtVerifier.verify(jwtToken);
    if (decodedJWT.getClaim("role").equals("coach")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Yes, I know, this is not the way to log in since nothing is checked, but I want to see if this code works first, so when i navigate to http://localhost:8080/coach/login in Postman I receive a jwtToken:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ3aXNlYml0ZWRldGFpbHMiLCJyb2xlIjoiY29hY2giLCJuYmYiOjE3MDk3MTM3ODQsImlzcyI6Indpc2ViaXRlIiwiZXhwIjoxNzA5NzEzNzg4LCJpYXQiOjE3MDk3MTM3ODMsImp0aSI6ImY4Zjc3NzkxLTlmYjgtNDNlNi1iNTFjLTRlOTk1ZDQ2NGZmYyJ9.8sitspmE0N_Ai47qrIQmrp4szVc4mwDANlpN5L0jJbg
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/coach/overview/user and put this jwtToken in the body, I get the error saying it's not base64 encoded...

Below is the @Getmapping

```
@GetMapping("/overview/{username}")
private ResponseEntity<PlanDTO> getPlanByClient(@PathVariable String username,
                                                @RequestBody String jwtToken) {
    if (authenticationService.hasAcces(jwtToken)) {
```

I'm using the Auth0 library version 4.2.1
I think that's about all the information I have available, what am I doing wrong?